# RGBApixel’ has no member named...red blue and green

Tags: c++, rgb, pixel, bmp, rgba

I'm getting multiple errors stating, "'RGBApixel’ has no member named ‘red'", "'RGBApixel’ has no member named ‘green', and "'RGBApixel’ has no member named ‘blue'". Not sure why because I'm using EasyBMP library.

In the function below I am locating a pixel within a BMP image then comparing the rgb value of that pixel to color1 and color2 rgb values. The pixel will get changed to the color closest to it:

```
BMP Preprocessor (BMP pix, RGBApixel color1, RGBApixel color2, int xlow, int xhigh, int ylow, int yhigh){

  for (int i = xlow; i < xhigh; i++){
    for (int j = ylow; j < yhigh; j++){

      RGBApixel pixel = pix.GetPixel(i,j);

      double distance1 = abs(pixel.red - color1.red) + abs(pixel.green - color1.green) + abs(pixel.blue - color1.blue);

      double distance2 = abs(pixel.red - color2.red) + abs(pixel.green - color2.green) + abs(pixel.blue - color2.blue);

      if (distance1 < distance2) { // pixel color closest to color1
        pixel.red = color1.red;
        pixel.green = color1.green;
        pixel.blue = color1.blue;

      }  
      else { // pixel color closest to color2
        pixel.red = color2.red;
        pixel.green = color2.green;
        pixel.blue = color2.blue;
      }
    }
  }
  return pix;
}
```

Comment: How are you including the headers for the library?

Comment: Can you show us the definition of RGBApixel?

Comment: #include "EasyBMP.h"

Comment: User Manual of Easy BMP https://www.scribd.com/doc/4084197/EasyBMP-UserManual

Answer (score 2):

I found this code sample on easybmp.sourceforge.net:

```
RGBApixel FontColor;
FontColor.Red = 255; FontColor.Green = 0; FontColor.Blue = 0;
```

So it seems that the 'Red', 'Green', and 'Blue' members use capital letters, whereas in your code you're attempting to access them using lowercase letters. So your compiler is right, the members your trying to access dont exist.

Simply change the lines that access the members from `pixel.red` etc. to `pixel.Red`.